# How to navigate out of a ActionSheet?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-actionsheet

how to navigate out of a `ActionSheet` where I can only Pass a `Text` but not a `NavigationLink`?

Sample Code:

```
struct DemoActionSheetNavi: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            Text("Test")

            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                ActionSheet(
                    title: Text("What do you want to do?"),
                    message: Text("There's only one choice..."),
                    buttons: [
                        .default(Text("How to navigate from here to HelpView???")),
                ])
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need something like this:

```
struct DemoActionSheetNavi: View {

    @State private var showingSheet = false
    @State private var showingHelp = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Test")
                Button("Tap me") { self.showingSheet = true }
                NavigationLink(destination: HelpView(isShowing: $showingHelp),
                               isActive: $showingHelp) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
            
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            ActionSheet(
                title: Text("What do you want to do?"),
                message: Text("There's only one choice..."),
                buttons: [.cancel(),
                          .default(Text("Go to help")) {
                            self.showingSheet = false
                            self.showingHelp = true
                    }])
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

You have another state that programmatically triggers a `NavigationLink` (you could also do it using `.sheet` and modal presentation). You would also need to pass showingHelp as a `@Binding` to help view to be able to reset it.

```
struct HelpView: View {
    
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text("Help view")
            .onDisappear() { self.isShowing = false }
        
    }
    
}
```